# How to sign the BinarySecurityToken by configuration instead of code

Tags: wcf, soap, digital-signature, x509, wcf-security

We have to consume a service from an external party and we were having issues because the BinarySecurityToken was not being signed in the SOAP message.

We found several online references that finally helped us and it all comes down to the fact that we have to create a custom binding where we prevent the inclusion of both the InitiatorToken and RecipientToken and add a new EndpointSupportingToken:

```
bindingElement.InitiatorTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
bindingElement.RecipientTokenParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters { InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.Never };
bindingElement.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(new X509SecurityTokenParameters());
```

Here is the configuration for the custom binding:

```
<customBinding>
  <binding name="SecuredSadmiBinding" sendTimeout="00:02:00" receiveTimeout="00:02:00">
    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap11" writeEncoding="utf-8">
      <readerQuotas maxArrayLength="2147483647" 
                    maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" 
                    maxDepth="2147483647" 
                    maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" 
                    maxStringContentLength="2147483647"/>
    </textMessageEncoding>
    <security authenticationMode="MutualCertificateDuplex" 
              enableUnsecuredResponse="true" 
              securityHeaderLayout="LaxTimestampLast"
              messageSecurityVersion="WSSecurity11WSTrust13WSSecureConversation13WSSecurityPolicy12"
              includeTimestamp="true" 
              defaultAlgorithmSuite="Basic128Rsa15"
              messageProtectionOrder="SignBeforeEncrypt"
              requireDerivedKeys="false"
              requireSignatureConfirmation="false">
      <localClientSettings timestampValidityDuration="00:01:00" />
      <secureConversationBootstrap />
    </security>
    <httpsTransport maxBufferSize="2147483647" 
                    maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"
                    requireClientCertificate="false" />
  </binding>
</customBinding>
```

Our question is whether or not setting the inclusion mode to never for the InitiatorToken and RecipientToken is possible by configuration rather than by code. The same question for the EndpointSupportingToken.

Comment: Hi, Did you solve this ?